# Bash seems to ignore BASH_ENV when providing multiple commands to SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

From Jenkins I try to send bash scripts to a host, where those bash scripts should be run. All those scripts have to be run in the same directory on the host. I do not want to provide this directory to each script, so I would like to `cd` into this directory and then run the script.

On the host the default shell is `/bin/sh`. In my `.bashrc` I set some variables, so I instruct bash to load my `.bashrc` with `BASH_ENV`. I run scripts with `ssh user@host BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' 'bash -s' < myscript.sh $appdir`. This actually works, now when I remove `$appdir` from `myscript.sh` and `ssh user@host BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' "cd $appdir ; bash -s" < myscript.sh`, variables from `.bashrc` are no longer available.

Following is a simple reproduction of this problem, only user, host and /path/to/git have been changed after the commands have been executed. `git` is added to `$PATH` in `.bashrc`, otherwise it is not available.

This works:

```sh
$ ssh user@host BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' 'bash -c "type git" ; pwd'
git is /path/to/git
/home/user
```

This does not work:

```sh
$ ssh user@host BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' 'cd ; bash -c "type git" ; pwd'
bash: line 0: type: git: not found
/home/user
```

There are different parts of SSH and Bash that I do not understand. I would be grateful for any information that would help me understand this problem.

Comment: `ssh user@host "export BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc'; cd $appdir && bash -s" < myscript.sh`

Comment: ssh builds the remote command by simply concatenating its arguments: `ssh -v user@host BASH_ENV='~/.bashrc' "cd $appdir;" "bash true" 2>&1 | grep Sending.command`

Comment: @jhnc Thank you! `export` did the trick. Just concatenating its arguments - now it starts making sense. `-v` and `2>&1 | grep Sending.command` will help a lot.